# Ground symbol from circuits.ee.IEC library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I wish to draw a ground symbol in a circuit diagram using the circuits.ee.IEC TiKZ library. The example in the [PGF Manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (pdf) on page 311 shows exactly what I want. However, when I try to draw it, the wire is extended beyond the ground symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to[ground] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ground symbol does not end wire]

How do I fix this, so the ground symbol ends the wire as in the example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can supply `pos=1` to the `ground` key to position the symbol at the end of the line instead of in the middle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to [ground={pos=1}] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Or, as percusse suggested in a comment, you could place the symbol as a "proper" node instead of passing it to the `to` keyword. Note that you'll have to supply an empty set of brackets and use the `right` keyword (and an appropriate `rotate` option if the wire isn't going from left to right).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0) node [ground, right] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you don't make it a connecting node and place it at the end `\draw (0,0) -- (3,0) node[ground,right]{};`

Comment: I had to use `\draw (0,0) to [ground={pos=1, right}] (3,0);` for some reason.