# How do I typeset the ground symbol ⏚ in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, engineering

How do I type the [ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%28electricity%29) symbol ⏚ in LaTeX?

I am not trying to create a ground node in a circuit diagram (which is answered in [a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70437/ground-symbol-from-circuits-ee-iec-library)). Instead, I just want to be able to type the symbol ⏚ in math mode.

Answer (score 13):

One option is to define a command for this symbol taking it, for example, from the `circuits.ee.IEC` library (I wasn't sure if this symbol should be ord, rel, bin, so I opted for bin; also, there was no information about size or baseline position, but all these attributes can easily be adjusted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\newcommand\Ground{%
\mathbin{\text{\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,yscale=0.6,xscale=0.5]
\draw (0,2ex) to (0,0) node[ground,rotate=-90,xshift=.65ex] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$L\Ground {}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option: this is listed as Unicode character [`'EARTH GROUND' (U+23DA)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23da/index.htm), so you could use XeLaTeX and a font supporting the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola}

\begin{document}
The earth ground symbol $⏚$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`fileformat.info`](http://www.fileformat.info/) has a [`list of possible fonts supporting the symbol`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23da/fontsupport.htm).

Comment: Your first solution no longer works (it produces something quite strange).  Perhaps a tikz library changed over time...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Indeed; apparently the `ground` symbol from `circuits.ee.IEC` changed. I've fixed the answer accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.